# Passing data using state in Link tag in React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't know where I'm wrong. I want to pass that parameter as a state to Link tag and get that in another component.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class CategoryList extends React.Component{


    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <Link to={{pathname:"/Topics/" + this.props.row.Occupation+"/"+this.props.row.objectId +'/id'+'/'+this.props.userName, state:{description:this.props.row.Description}}}>
                        {this.props.row.Occupation}
                    </Link>
                </td>
                <td>{this.props.row.Description}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

index.js

```
<Route path="/Topics/:Occupation/:objectId/:id/:userName" component={Main} />
```

I want to pass it here and access the state given in  Link tag. So your help will be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you pass data to the state object in the Link, you can access this data in the routed component(In your case it is the  Main component), like this:

```
props.location.state
```

Comment: This is the correct way.Maybe the data you are passing through the Link is undefined?

Answer (score 5):

You need not pass any extra values to the route. You can achieve what you desire by providing extra objects to the link object.

Something on the lines of -

```
 <Link to={{pathname:"/Topics/", customObject: customValue}}>
```

and then you can access it from `this.props.location.customObject`

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#link), you can do something like this

`<Link to={{ pathname: '/hello', query: { name: 'ryan' } }}>
  Hello
</Link>`

And in a new path, you can get that name using props.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late to provide a solution, you might have got a solution, But my solution can also work for others who are facing the same issue. I have done something like this

```
public loadPage(data) {
    browserHistory.push({
        pathname: '/am/activate',
        state: data
    });
}
```

On the other component you can access this value

```
this.props.location.state
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use this sample code

2.Passing Data(object):

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

/* ... */

const myData = {
   name: 'Some thing',
   price: 123
}

/* ... */

<Link to="/some-where" state={myData}>Link Text</Link>
```

3.Retrieving Data(object):

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

/*...*/

const location = useLocation();
const data = location.state;
console.log(data);
```

For more: https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-router-passing-data-states-through-links/